# Problema en envio de correo con PHP

Tags: php, email

necesito ayuda, estoy haciendo un formulario en php al momento de guardarlo me deberia llegar un correo electronico con los datos que llene en el formulario y con la foto que adjunto pero cuando lo ejecuto solo me llega la foto que adjunte y no el resto de los datos que puse en el formulario, alguien sabe como poder solucionarlo??

esta es la parte donde se arma el correo:

```
    $correoDestino = "rodrigomunita14@gmail.com";

    $asunto = "enviado por" . $nombreContacto;

    $cabecera = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;";
    $cabecera .= "boundary=\"=C=T=E=C=\"\r\n";
    $cabecera .= "From: {$email}";

    $cuerpo = "--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: text/plain";
    $cuerpo .= "charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Nombre Contacto: ". $nombreContacto ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Cargo en empresa: ". $cargoEmpresa ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Nombre de la Empresa: ". $nombreEmpresa ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Direccion: ". $direccion ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Telefono: ". $telefono ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Email: ". $email ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Producto: ". $Producto2[0] ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Cantidad: ". $cantidad ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Costo: ". $valor ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Comentarios: ". $comentarios ."\r\n";
    $cuerpo .="Fecha de envio del formulario: ". $fechaFormato;
    $cuerpo .="\r\n";

    $cuerpo .="--=C=T=E=C=\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ";
    $cuerpo .= "name=" . $nameFile . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
    $cuerpo .= "filename=" . $nameFile . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";

    $fp = fopen($tempFile, "rb");
    $file = fread($fp, $sizeFile);
    $file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

    $cuerpo .= "$file\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "\r\n";

    $cuerpo .= "--=C=T=E=C=--\r\n";

    if($cantidad > 49){
        mail($correoDestino, $asunto, $cuerpo, $cabecera);
    }
```

Comment: Si no te vienen los datos en el email, pero sí el texto que has puesto en el cuerpo, comprueba que recibes bien los datos del formulario, y que asignas bien los valores a las variables que utilizas para el cuerpo.

Comment: Has probado cambiar ```Content-Type: text/plain``` por ```Content-Type: text/html```, quizas te soluciona.